# Converting int to str to display in messagebox Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am creating a number guessing game for an extra assignment, as a bonus from guessing the number it needs to keep a count of how many tries and display them in the winning message, however I keep getting: TypeError: can only concatentate str (not 'int) to str.
I am trying to get tries to show up in the variable e, and looking up how to implement the counter of tries.

P.s. I am still learning

```
tries = 0
str(tries)
b='You guessed the number! '
c= 'Do you want to play again?'
d='It took you'
e=b+d+tries+c


def Guesser():
    try:
        guess=int(turtle.textinput('Guess the Number!','Guess a number between 1 and 100!'))
        if guess==a:
            winner=messagebox.askquestion('Guess the Number!',e)
            if winner=='yes':
                Guesser()
            else:
                quitter
        elif guess<=a:
            messagebox.showinfo('Guess the Number!','You need to guess higher!')
            Guesser()
        elif guess>=a:
            messagebox.showinfo('Guess the Number!','You need to guess lower!')
            Guesser()
    except Exception as e:
    messagebox.showwarning('Guess the Number!','You have not entered a number. Please enter a number between 1 and 100!')
        quitter=messagebox.askquestion('Guess the Number!','Do you want to quit?')
        if quitter=='yes':
            quit            
        else:
            Guesser()
```

Comment: Hint: You run `str(tries)` but you don't assign the statement so it doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Even when you fix the problem that has been pointed out, this isn't actually going to work as you expect, as you only generate `e` *once*, as the program is starting up.  The string isn't going to magically change later, just because one of the variables that was used to create it has changed.

Comment: What is the `a`?

Comment: forgot to add `a`, it is used to produce a random integer from 1 to 100

Answer (score 1):

First, you are using `str()` incorrectly.

The `str()` method, doesn't convert the value of your variable, it **returns the specified value converted into a string**. Check this: [*Python str() Function*](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_str.asp).

So, if you want `tries` as a *String* you can do it this way:

```py
tries = str(0)
b = 'You guessed the number! '
c = 'Do you want to play again?'
d = 'It took you'
e = b + d + tries + c
```

But if you just want it as *String* to concatentate in `e` you can do this way:

```py
tries = 0
b = 'You guessed the number! '
c = 'Do you want to play again?'
d = 'It took you'
e = b + d + str(tries) + c
```

Second, **you have a logic problem here**. You are not counting the tries and even if you was, you generate `e` before the win, so **`tries` will always be zero**.

But, you can solve it this way:

```py
tries = 0

def Guesser():
    global tries
    tries+= 1
    try:
        guess=int(turtle.textinput('Guess the Number!','Guess a number between 1 and 100!'))
        if guess==a:
            winner=messagebox.askquestion('Guess the Number!', 'You guessed the number! It took you {}. Do you want to play again?'.format(tries))
            if winner=='yes':
                Guesser()
            else:
                quitter
        elif guess<=a:
            messagebox.showinfo('Guess the Number!','You need to guess higher!')
            Guesser()
        elif guess>=a:
            messagebox.showinfo('Guess the Number!','You need to guess lower!')
            Guesser()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        messagebox.showwarning('Guess the Number!','You have not entered a number. Please enter a number between 1 and 100!')
        quitter=messagebox.askquestion('Guess the Number!','Do you want to quit?')
        if quitter=='yes':
            quit            
        else:
            Guesser()
```

**Note**: I've used [`format()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp) method, and now `str()` is no more necessary.

Comment: Thank you, this has corrected the first problem, as jasonharper commented i still need it to provide the full message when a win occurs.
As well as count each try.

Comment: This is awesome, first time here and every answer/comment has been so helpful.

If i put that block in a while loop to calculate the amount of times it's been run and throw the output to `tries`, would that give me what i need?

Comment: Thanks, I did try your second option with the removal of `str()` however I get this error from that.

`UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'tries' where it is not associated with a value`

I am new so i don't have enough rep to upvote, but everyone here has helped a great deal already, I can only offer my gratitude.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put the global declaration.

Comment: Ah, yeah we've not learnt about globals yet, but thanks so much for your help Diego.

Comment: I've used a global to do a simple solution, but, I recommend that you use `OOP`. I mean, create the class `Guesser` and put the field `tries` inside it, then, put your method inside the class.

Comment: I don't know if you already learned `OOP`, so maybe [this](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/)  can help you :)